# How to make an <img> element tiled over all elements in a webpage without using CSS background properties

Tags: html, css, background-image

I want to tile an image through the entire web document which I want to print. I have used background property to tile that, but I have to set the z-index property to make that image placed over all elements of the web page. Help me solve this.

Comment: You know you can set the option to print "background" images?

Comment: Can you place a CSS background image tiled over all elements in the document? Can you set z-index to a background image?

Comment: Yes and Yes! Maybe if you where a little clearer with your exact requirements, what you have actually tried, showing some code then people would be in a better place to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

stick it to the root style

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>

 :root 
   {
     background-image:url("https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQRxExzbsZCvO6lpE1tll_7pQLB5nd4RkWkrMannssfhAYni_Ct");
  opacity: .4; 
      }

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="overlay" onclick="off()"></div>

<div style="padding:20px">
  <h2>Overlay</h2>
  <p>Add an overlay effect to the page content (100% width and height with background with 40% opacity).</p>
  <button>some button here</button>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, but sorry, it doesn't solve my case. The background property applies image behind all the elements on the page. I want the image to be placed over the top of all elements.

Comment: ok, sorry, now it's over all elements. you can set opacity or remove it